# Hilbert basis of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $V$ a vector space with inner product and $X\subset V$ orthonormal. Prove that exists a Hilbert basis (an orthonormal set of vectors with the property that every vector in $V$ can be written as an infinite linear combination of the vectors in the basis) such that $X\subset B$.

I can consider $B=X\cup X^{\perp}$ and this set will be maximal, but I am not sure about this, is it correct?

Another idea is using the Zorn lemma, but I need a "chain", how can I build this chain?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider all orthonormal systems $B$ containing $X$. By definition put $B_1\leq B_2$ if $B_1\subset B_2$. To prove that maximal system (which existence is guaranteed by Zorn's lemma) is a basis consider orthogonal complement of it.